# Links that doesn't look like links

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, web-crawler, permalinks

I have some codes that gets all the links of a page, but some were getting links that doesn't look like links. For example, indexes 0-4 was getting links called "javascript:void(0)", and index 5 was getting a blank link with just a "/". How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://bestspace.co"); //get content of page

$links = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>"; //set regular expression to get links
preg_match_all("/$links/siU", $content, $matches); //get all links on page and store in array $matches[2]

print_r($matches[2]);
```

**contents of array**

```
Array ( 

[0] => javascript:void(0) 
[1] => javascript:void(0) 
[2] => javascript:void(0) 
[3] => javascript:void(0) 
[4] => javascript:void(0) 
[5] => / 
[6] => /bestdeals 
[7] => /about-us 
[8] => /why-choose-us 
[9] => /products 
[10] => https://cloud.bestspace.co/clientarea.php 

ect... );
```

Comment: What is a `link` to you? Those are the values of the `href`s. You could modify regex so the `href`'s value starts with a `/` or `http`. The 10th value is the only one I would consider a link.

Comment: Are you expecting it to *only* return fully qualified URLs? Please clarify what you mean by "links"

Comment: @JesseFulton I would say 6-10 are all links.

Comment: `/` is a perfectly valid href...will take you to root of site. All except the `javascript:void()` are valid web paths

Comment: @charlietfl Ok. Well, how do I get rid of javascript:void()? Well, not get rid off. But how do I not get it in the first place.

Comment: Use `array_filter` to remove any entries that begin with `javacscript:`.

Comment: @charlietfl When I called preg_match_all to match the links, how do I not get links link javascript:void()?

Comment: Try fiddling with this, https://regex101.com/r/tY6vP8/1. Without input hard to give an expected result.

Comment: @Barmar Something like this? $matches[2] = array_filter($matches[2], 'javascript:void(0)');

Comment: Why only `javascript:void(0)`? You should probably filter out ALL Javascript links, since you can't follow them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_filter` to remove all the Javascript links.

```
$links = array_filter($matches[2], function($x) {
    return substr($x, 0, 11) != 'javascript:';
});
```

Comment: You mean !==. You forgot the !